# Can we say that a "triangulation" of a surface is a "triangular tessellation" of that surface?

Tags: geometry, terminology, riemann-surfaces

I came across the following two concepts during my self-study of Riemann surfaces,

- Tessellation (Tiling): Subdivision of a geometric surface into non-overlapping polygons
- Triangulation: Subdivision of a geometric surface into non-overlapping triangles

Can we say that the triangulation is a Triangular tessellation, i.e., the tessellation is a general version of the triangulation…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can... probably. Tessellation is just another name for tiling, and there are no restrictions on the shapes you use to do that (other than not leaving any gaps); triangulation would generally come under the heading of "aperiodic tiling". The only fly in the ointment is the question of approximation; that is, the triangulation is extremely unlikely to cover the surface perfectly (especially if it's got nonzero curvature), so can we really say that it's been tiled? I'm fine with saying "yes" to that, but opinions will no doubt vary.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your answer!